# Formatting of numbers in trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger that increments a number by one each time a record is inserted.
The trigger works on normal numbers, however I need to set the number to be like this: `Q1500/11/2017` (11 being month, 2017 being year and it will roll over according to the month and year).

The Q1500 will increase each time so starting from Q1500 it will go Q1501/11/2017, Q1502/11/2017 and just continue.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT
    Quote_No = 'Q' + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), CONVERT(INT, Quote_No) + 1) + '/' + 
    RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), 7) 
FROM
    Quote_Pref_No 
WHERE
    ID = 1
```

The above returns a null value.

Table Quote_Pref_no is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Quote_Pref_no]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Quote_No] [nvarchar](50) NULL DEFAULT ('Q1500'),
    [Mth] [nvarchar](3) Null,
    [Year] [nvarchar](4) Null
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How can I set the number to return the correct format and increment the Quote no by one?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using? Are you 100% sure, that all input values are not null?

Comment: second time 'Q1502/11/2017' is used to derive Q1501/11/2017. Correct.?

Answer (score 0):

```
select Quote_No = 'Q' + '/' + CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(Quote_No,2,LEN(Quote_No)) AS BIGINT)+ 1 AS VARCHAR(50)) + '/' + MONTH(GETDATE())+YEAR(GETDATE()) from Quote_Pref_No where ID = 1
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014. The input values cannot be null. each record needs to have a value.
The above code says incorrect syntax near As

Comment: I get this error with the above code:

Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Set_QUDF_For_New_Opps, Line 23
Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DECLARE @Quote_No nvarchar(50)='Q1500'
DECLARE @i INT=1

WHILE(@i<=10)
BEGIN

   IF(CHARINDEX('/',@Quote_No)!=0)
   BEGIN
     SELECT @Quote_No = LEFT(@Quote_No, CHARINDEX('/',@Quote_No)-1)
   END

   SELECT @Quote_No = 'Q'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(@Quote_No,LEN(@Quote_No)-1))+1)+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MONTH(GETDATE()))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(GETDATE())) 

   SELECT @Quote_No

   SET @i=@i+1
END
```